# How to get Intellisense on error-marked code in Visual Studio 2005?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

When I try to compile code on VS 2005 and it fails, the line which causes the error gets underlined blue, and mouse-hovering over it displays the error message. Fine, but you can't see object types or whatever, because Intellisense will show the error message, and not object info.

In this image, I wanted to see what type `DateTime.Subtract()` returns, but VS insists on showing the error message:

[alt text http://img502.imageshack.us/img502/6962/vs2005errordl7.png](http://img502.imageshack.us/img502/6962/vs2005errordl7.png)

Does anyone know how to get the error message out of the way, **once you've got enough of it**?

Comment: By the way, took me some time to notice that Subtract(TimeSpan) returns a DateTime and Subtract(DateTime) returns a TimeSpan :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select "Build|Clean Solution" - this cleans up intermediate files and other things. More importantly, it also clears the list of error messages, restoring normal behaviour of Intellisense.

Answer (score 1):

Cut the first part of the line ("DateTime duracao = ") into the clipboard, then you should be able to hover over "Subtract" and see the return type. Not ideal, but I find myself doing it all the time!

Answer (score 0):

ctrl-space inside the parens

Comment: Doesn't help. What if I wanted to know the type of Value?

Answer (score 0):

I just found that the equivalent to mouse hovering is `View -> IntelliSense -> Quick Info`. If the solution does not arise here, I'll just use the shortcut `Ctrl+K, Ctrl+I`.

Comment: Problem with this one: F1 still goes to the documentation of the error, not of whatever else I want.

Answer (score 0):

Since duracao is a DateTime, and the error message is 'cannot convert **Timespan** to **DateTime'** - you can already see the subtract function is returning a Timespan